# stripe: Create a 30-day trial subscription charge on a saved card but allow user to upgrade and start charging immediately?

Tags: javascript, node.js, stripe-payments

So before a user can create an account I want to save their credit card to charge a subscription with 30 day trial AND the ability to immediately charge the card for a subscription if the user demands it.

so my logic is to

1) create a customer

2) add payment details for customer

3) create subscription with 30 day trial

4) activate subscription upon user upgrade action

I'm not clear on how 4) is possible. I get that on 3), after 30 days, they are on a subscription. but what if the customer wants to start using the full version immediately before the trial is over, how would I create a charge for the subscription?

```
const stripe = require('stripe')('sk_test_asdfasdf');
(async () => {
  // Create a Customer:
stripe.customers.create({
  email: 'jenny.rosen@example.com',
  payment_method: 'pm_1FWS6ZClCIKljWvsVCvkdyWg',
  invoice_settings: {
    default_payment_method: 'pm_1FWS6ZClCIKljWvsVCvkdyWg',
  },
}, function(err, customer) {
  // asynchronously called
});

//create subscription
stripe.subscriptions.create({
  customer: 'cus_4fdAW5ftNQow1a',
  items: [
    {
      plan: 'plan_CBXbz9i7AIOTzr',
    },
  ],
  expand: ['latest_invoice.payment_intent'],
}, function(err, subscription) {
    // asynchronously called
  }
);

})();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll chime in on this really quick, to hopefully get you in the right direction; This sounds like a case for Setup Intents. You can collect payment details, with the *intent* to charge at a later time. Since the trial won't incur any charges at first, all is good. However you work out the logic to switch from trial to active status on the subscription, you'd update the subscription end-date to end the trial.

This is nicely summarized here, for the most part, save for updating the Subscription and setting the `trial_end` argument:

https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-and-reuse

API docs entry on updating the Subscription:

https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/update#update_subscription-trial_end

Once the trial is over, whether "naturally" or by explicitly setting the end timestamp, an invoice should be sent out or default payment method charged, depending on your settings. It wouldn't hurt to work in some good flow here, concerning user-experience; For example, having a confirmation step to let the customer know they are about to be charged X amount, before actually firing off that off.

Here are other helpful docs:

- https://stripe.com/docs/saving-cards
- https://stripe.com/docs/payments/setup-intents
- https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/trials
- https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/payment#handling-trial
- https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/update